# How to test Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-jetpack-compose

I use the new Jetpack Compose, now comes time to test UI. Does anyone know the tools for testing it?
Since Espresso mainly relies on view I don't think that it can help.

Comment: For screenshot testing please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69176420/8583692).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android has a code sample ([Jetnews](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetNews)) that includes a couple of UI tests. This may help you to set up some tests or in the future, they may add additional code samples around UI testing.

Edit: [Link to Jetnews UI Tests](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/56822faf2e4022bbc171123cf12bf832183171bf/JetNews/app/src/sharedTest/java/com/example/jetnews/JetnewsTests.kt)

Comment: Worth noting that currently there's no way to report on Code Coverage when doing Instrumented Tests with JetpackCompose's Components - so if a code coverage report is something you're interested on you might want to subscribe to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1208) for updates.

Answer (score 2):

In [goo.gle/compose-testing](https://goo.gle/compose-testing) you'll find the official documentation.

Most of the [official code samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) have UI tests. Apart from the common UI checks in JetNews, you can find animation+screenshot tests in Rally, Interop tests in Crane, screen recreation and navigation tests in Jetchat, etc.