# Take screenshot of a composable fun programmatically in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I would like to capture the UI emitted by Jetpack compose as a Bitmap. In XML this was done like this:

Basically takes a view as an input parameter and returns it as a Bitmap.

```
//take screenshot of the view added as an input argument
fun takeScreenShot(view: View) : Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.width,
        view.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

What is the equivalent of this in Jetpack compose?

Comment: See also https://github.com/JohannBlake/bitmap-from-composable for an example of using a `ComposeView` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

There is a new multiplatform Kotlin library (also supporting Android Views and Compose Multiplatform): [Comshot](https://github.com/mahozad/comshot)

---

Taking screenshots from a composable is possible in **tests**.
For taking screenshots in production code see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63861095/8583692) and [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198182887).

First, make sure you have the following dependency in your build script (along with other required Compose dependencies):

```kotlin
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:<version>")
```

<sup>Note: Instead of the above dependency, you can simply add *AndroidManifest.xml* in *androidTest* directory and in the  `manifest`>`application` element add this: `<activity android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity"/>`.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354577/8583692).</sup>

Here is a complete example for saving, reading, and comparing screenshots:
(Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69259011/8583692) for setting up write permissions and so on for the tests)

```kotlin
class ScreenshotTest {

    @get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test fun takeAndSaveScreenshot() {
        composeTestRule.setContent { MyComposableFunction() }
        val node = composeTestRule.onRoot()
        val screenshot = node.captureToImage().asAndroidBitmap()
        saveScreenshot("screenshot.png", screenshot)
    }

    @Test fun readAndCompareScreenshots() {
        composeTestRule.setContent { MyComposableFunction() }
        val node = composeTestRule.onRoot()
        val screenshot = node.captureToImage().asAndroidBitmap()

        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(path, "screenshot.png")
        val saved = readScreenshot(file)

        println("Are screenshots the same: ${screenshot.sameAs(saved)}")
    }

    private fun readScreenshot(file: File) = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path)

    private fun saveScreenshot(filename: String, screenshot: Bitmap) {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        // Saves in /Android/data/your.package.name.test/files/Pictures on external storage
        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(path, filename)
        file.outputStream().use { stream ->
            screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to Google Codelabs for [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/compose/rally/ScreenshotComparator.kt).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at how JP-Compose testing does this.

A good starting point could be the [android-compose-codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs), see:

```
/**
 * Simple on-device screenshot comparator that uses golden images present in
 * `androidTest/assets`. It's used to showcase the [AnimationClockTestRule] used in
 * [AnimatingCircleTests].
 *
 * Minimum SDK is O. Densities between devices must match.
 *
 * Screenshots are saved on device in `/data/data/{package}/files`.
 */
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun assertScreenshotMatchesGolden(
    goldenName: String,
    node: SemanticsNodeInteraction
) {
    val bitmap = node.captureToImage().asAndroidBitmap()
}
```

from [ScreenshotComparator.kt](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/TestingCodelab/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/compose/rally/ScreenshotComparator.kt). You can find `captureToImage()` here in the [AndroidHelpers.kt](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/ui/ui-test/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/AndroidImageHelpers.android.kt).

Also you can find here the [ImageBitmap.kt](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/ui/ui-graphics/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/ImageBitmap.kt), where [asAndroidBitmap()](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/ui/ui-graphics/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/AndroidImageBitmap.android.kt) only makes sure that, the underlying "common" version of the ImageBitmap is actually an `android.graphics.Bitmap` on Android (this is to make the code more platform agnostic, so that it can be run on the JVM/desktop as well)

Comment: Can we access the screenshot progrmatically this way? To do something like upload it to cloud storage